# how to set connection string such as sessionVariables=transaction_isolation='READ-COMMITTED' using sqlx in Golang

Tags: mysql, go, sqlx

hello we are trying to set some session variables when connecting to the mysql DB during our golang server startup, we are using https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx the API for connection is https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#Open and https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#Connect I am not sure where to pass extra connection strings such as session variables. Does anyone know?

Comment: probably the dataSourceName parameter of the methods are the full connection string, needs to verify.

Comment: Some parameters can be set in the connection string: `[username[:password]@][protocol[(address)]]/dbname[?param1=value1&...&paramN=valueN]` according to [mysql driver docs](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#dsn-data-source-name). Transaction isolation can be set when beginning a transaction, see [BeginTxx](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#Conn.BeginTxx).